# ASP.NET Core Web API : json body

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui

A web service I developed on ASP.NET Core works, also in Swagger and when using Postman, everything works smoothly and as I want.

Cisco wants the json body to be sent as single quotes on the CCX side. When I replace the double quotes in the json body with single quotes, the web service gives an error. Is there any way to fix this and make the service detect single quotes?

CCX Json:

```
{ 'serverName': 'myServer.domain.com' }
```

Web Service response:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-a93e09028c78d685900520cfe2702830-2c271adc36377644-00",
    "errors": {
        "$": [
                 "''' is an invalid start of a property name. Expected a '\"'. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
             ]
    }
}
```

I tried sending it as TextJson but I cannot find a solution.

Comment: single quotes will not be valid JSON. Can you maybe send the response as a string, then before trying to convert JSON to an object replace single with double quotes?

Answer (score 2):

So I could not find easy way with using standard `System.Text.Json` library, but got it working using Newtonsoft library and [`JsonTextWriter.QuoteChar`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter_QuoteChar.htm) property, below sample API with two endpoints - both return the same data, but one is using single quote character:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

static WeatherForecast[] GetRandomForecast()
{
    var summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index =>
        new WeatherForecast
        (
            DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
        ))
        .ToArray();
}

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
{
    WeatherForecast[] forecast = GetRandomForecast();
    return forecast;
})
.WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
.WithOpenApi();

app.MapGet("/weatherforecastsinglequotes", () =>
{
    var forecast = GetRandomForecast();
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    using var sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    using var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
    jsonWriter.QuoteChar = '\'';
    var serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, forecast);

    return sb.ToString();
})
.WithName("GetWeatherForecastSignleQuotes")
.WithOpenApi();

app.Run();

internal record WeatherForecast(DateOnly Date, int TemperatureC, string? Summary)
{
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}
```

And below you can compare the results:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2023-11-11",
    "temperatureC": -8,
    "summary": "Scorching",
    "temperatureF": 18
  },
  {
    "date": "2023-11-12",
    "temperatureC": 17,
    "summary": "Chilly",
    "temperatureF": 62
  },
  {
    "date": "2023-11-13",
    "temperatureC": 47,
    "summary": "Cool",
    "temperatureF": 116
  },
  {
    "date": "2023-11-14",
    "temperatureC": 50,
    "summary": "Warm",
    "temperatureF": 121
  },
  {
    "date": "2023-11-15",
    "temperatureC": 38,
    "summary": "Bracing",
    "temperatureF": 100
  }
]
```

and with single quotes:

```
[
  {
    'Date': '2023-11-11',
    'TemperatureC': 1,
    'Summary': 'Scorching',
    'TemperatureF': 33
  },
  {
    'Date': '2023-11-12',
    'TemperatureC': 32,
    'Summary': 'Warm',
    'TemperatureF': 89
  },
  {
    'Date': '2023-11-13',
    'TemperatureC': -10,
    'Summary': 'Mild',
    'TemperatureF': 15
  },
  {
    'Date': '2023-11-14',
    'TemperatureC': 28,
    'Summary': 'Hot',
    'TemperatureF': 82
  },
  {
    'Date': '2023-11-15',
    'TemperatureC': 8,
    'Summary': 'Scorching',
    'TemperatureF': 46
  }
]
```

Comment: Actually, the return of the service being double quoted is not a problem, it was a problem when the sent json data was posted.  In other words, it gives an error because there is a single quote in the sent json data, there is no different way of sending, I searched. 

https://community.cisco.com/t5/contact-center/uccx-rest-call-post-json-body/m-p/4308330

Comment: @BarışSakızlı well, you need to be more clear, i just wasted time on my research.

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion above and I'll let you know. I don't think I've explained my problem properly. I am preparing a picture to express it more clearly.